# How do i retrieve matched string of a paragraph using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a web application using PHP and MySQL. In my application I create a part for searching paragraph using FULL-TEXT search from mysql. e.g: In my database I have a paragraph that contains 1200 characters. I performed a query "test" and the word "test" in my paragraph is at middle location. I want to show only 200 characters with matched area. How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: What happens if "test" is in there multiple times in very different locations?

Comment: @jprofitt If "test" is in there multiple, So I want to retrieve 200 characters that are located with 1st "test"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use preg_match("#(.{0,100}$query.{0,100})#", $Data from Database, $matches);

This will assign the variable $matches with an array, element [0] should contain the word and up to 100 letters either side of the word/phrase searched for.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean ? What is the value of query ? It may be because it doesnt escape the search term ?

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing any of your syntax, this is something you could do:

```
$sp=strpos($word,$row['paragraph']);
echo "...".substr($row['paragraph'],$sp-100,200)."...";
```

Or if you want 100 characters before, and 100 after:

```
$sp=strpos($word,$row['paragraph']);
echo "...".substr($row['paragraph'],$sp-100,(200+strlen($word)))."...";
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  If it has 1+ words it will work just fine as long as the words are back to back in the paragraph.